# Как избежать повторения кода в наследуемых классах?

Tags: c#, инспекция-кода

Eсть базовый класс, от него наследуются другие, эти другие классы реализует в себе новые сущности, как избежать повторения одного и того же кода, при частичном повторении некоторых сущностей в наследуемых классах?
Важно то, что все новые сущности внутри наследуемых классов, принимают разные входящие значения.

```
// базовый класс
abstract class BaseStrategy
{
    // переменная для примера, она будет использована в наследуемом классе
    protected int VariableForSignal = 77;
    // переменная для примера, она будет использована в наследуемом классе
    protected int VariableForOpen = 5;

    // другой manager
    AnotherManager AnotherManager = new AnotherManager();

    // основная функция в которую поступают данные
    public void GetDecimalUpdate(decimal IncomeValue)
    {    
        // отпрашиваем первый фильтр
        if (!SignalFilterAnswer(IncomeValue))
            return;

        // опрашиваем второй фильтр
        if (!OpenFilterAnswer(IncomeValue))
            return;

        // опрашиваем третий фильтр
        if (!AnotherManager.ReturnAnswer())
            return;
    }

    // реализацию ответа фильтра оставляем наследуемым классам 
    protected abstract bool SignalFilterAnswer(decimal IncomeValue);

    // реализацию ответа фильтра оставляем наследуемым классам 
    protected abstract bool OpenFilterAnswer(decimal IncomeValue);
}

// наследуем базовый класс
class StupidPaperStrDiffStrategy : BaseStrategy
{
    // signal filter
    StrDiff StrDiff = new StrDiff();
    // open filter
    StupidPaper StupidPaper = new StupidPaper();

    // реализуем метод, который выполняет работу "signal filter"
    protected override bool SignalFilterAnswer(decimal IncomeValue)
    {
        // этот IF для того чтобы показать, что используются protected переменные базового класса
        if (VariableForSignal < IncomeValue)
            return StrDiff.ReturnAnswer(true, new int[] { 1, 2 });
        else
            return StrDiff.ReturnAnswer(false, new int[] { 2, 3 });
    }

    // реализуем метод, который выполняет работу "open filter"
    protected override bool OpenFilterAnswer(decimal IncomeValue)
    {
        // этот IF для того чтобы показать, что используются protected переменные базового класса
        if (VariableForOpen > IncomeValue)
            return StupidPaper.ReturnAnswer();
        else
            return StupidPaper.ReturnAnswer();
    }
}
```

Проблема в том, что когда я создаю еще один наследуемый класс, и в нем использую например реализацию `StrDiff`, но вместе `StupidPaper` будет `TimeFrame` реализация работы с `StrDiff` будет сразу в двух классах, как этого избежать?
Пример:

```
// наследуем базовый класс
class TimeFrameStrDiffStrategy : BaseStrategy
{
    // signal filter
    StrDiff StrDiff = new StrDiff();
    // open filter
    TimeFrame TimeFrame = new TimeFrame();

    // реализуем метод, который выполняет работу "signal filter"
    protected override bool SignalFilterAnswer(decimal IncomeValue)
    {
        //////////////////////////////////////////
        // Проблема находиться тут, этот код уже был написан в классе StupidPaperStrDiffStrategy и повторяется в этом классе
        /////////////////////////////////////////

        if (VariableForSignal < IncomeValue)
            return StrDiff.ReturnAnswer(true, new int[] { 1, 2 });
        else
            return StrDiff.ReturnAnswer(false, new int[] { 2, 3 });
    }

    // реализуем метод, который выполняет работу "open filter"
    protected override bool OpenFilterAnswer(decimal IncomeValue)
    {
        // этот IF для того чтобы показать, что используются protected переменные базового класса
        if (VariableForOpen > IncomeValue)
            return TimeFrame.ReturnAnswer(new byte[] { 144, 4 });
        else
            return TimeFrame.ReturnAnswer(new byte[] { 12, 4 });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно сделать второй абстрактный класс, который наследуется от `BaseStrategy` и реализует метод `SignalFilterAnswer`, но не реализует метод `OpenFilterAnswer`. Классы `StupidPaperStrDiffStrategy` и `TimeFrameStrDiffStrategy` наследуются от него и реализуют метод `OpenFilterAnswer`.

Comment: 'MiddleClass' does not implement inherited abstract member 'BaseStrategy.OpenFilterAnswer(decimal)' <br>Как можно его не реализовать?

Comment: объявить класс как abstract

Comment: большое Вам спасибо. Скажите это нормальная практика? Или следует как-то иначе реализовать данную задачу? Я к тому, что ответ Вы дали исходя из моего вопроса, а есть другие способы это реализовать?

Comment: Да, нормальная практика.

Comment: Есть другие способы, все зависит от того, сколько будет еще наследуемых классов и как они будут использоваться. Если только эти два, то можно сделать проще, убрать второй абстрактный класс и реализовать SignalFilterAnswer сразу внутри BaseStrategy.

Comment: Нет, наследуемых классов будет много и в каждом будут новые реализации вместо `StupidPaper` и `StrDiff`

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае, как я вижу, можно метод `SignalFilterAnswer` сделать `virtial` добавить ему реализацию по умолчанию прямо в классе `BaseStrategy` и удалить реализации этого метода у дочерних классов:

```
protected virtual bool SignalFilterAnswer(decimal IncomeValue)
{
    if (VariableForSignal < IncomeValue)
        return StrDiff.ReturnAnswer(true, new int[] { 1, 2 });
    else
        return StrDiff.ReturnAnswer(false, new int[] { 2, 3 });
}
```

Comment: Не получается, в классе `BaseStrategy` нету `StrDiff StrDiff = new StrDiff();`

Comment: Так добавьте. Или нельзя?

Comment: Не во всех наследуемых классах будет `StrDiff`, его тоже нужно будет менять как и `StupidPaper` на `TimeFrame`

Comment: @K.Oleg Если в наследниках кучу разных классов-полей которые друг от друга тесно зависят, то это признак плохой архитектуры. Используйте Dependency Injection или Inversion of control.