# Как избежать повторения кода в наследуемых классах? 2

Tags: c#

В этом вопросе, мне посоветовал создать дополнительный abstract class.
[Как избежать повторения кода в наследуемых классах?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/679218/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8B%D1%85-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%85)

К сожалению это не решило проблему, прошу Вашей помощи.
Важно то, что все новые сущности внутри наследуемых классов, принимают разные входящие значения.
Код:

```
//базовый класс
abstract class BaseStrategy
{
    //переменная для примера, она будет использована в наследуемом классе
    protected int VariableForSignal = 77;
    //переменная для примера, она будет использована в наследуемом классе
    protected int VariableForOpen = 5;

    //другой manager
    AnotherManager AnotherManager = new AnotherManager();

    //основная функция в которую поступают данные
    public void GetDecimalUpdate(decimal IncomeValue)
    {    
        //опрашиваем первый фильтр
        if(!SignalFilterAnswer(IncomeValue))
            return;

        //опрашиваем второй фильтр
        if(!OpenFilterAnswer(IncomeValue))
            return;

        //опрашиваем третий фильтр
        if(!AnotherManager.ReturnAnswer())
            return;
    }

    //реализацию ответа фильтра оставляем наследуемым классам 
    protected abstract bool SignalFilterAnswer(decimal IncomeValue);

    //реализацию ответа фильтра оставляем наследуемым классам 
    protected abstract bool OpenFilterAnswer(decimal IncomeValue);
}

//наследуем базовый класс, реализуя только метод OpenFilterAnswer
abstract class StupidPaperImplementation : BaseStrategy
{
    //open filter
    StupidPaper StupidPaper = new StupidPaper();

    //реализуем метод, который выполняет работу "open filter"
    protected override bool OpenFilterAnswer(decimal IncomeValue)
    {
        // этот IF для того чтобы показать, что используются protected переменные базового класса
        if(VariableForOpen > IncomeValue)
            return StupidPaper.ReturnAnswer();
        else
            return StupidPaper.ReturnAnswer();
    }
}

//наследуем StupidPaperImplementation и оставшуюся часть реализуем в этом классе
class StupidPaperStrDiffStrategy : StupidPaperImplementation
{
    //signal filter
    StrDiff StrDiff = new StrDiff();

    //реализуем метод, который выполняет работу "signal filter"
    protected override bool SignalFilterAnswer(decimal IncomeValue)
    {
        //этот IF для того чтобы показать, что используются protected переменные базового класса
        if(VariableForSignal < IncomeValue)
            return StrDiff.ReturnAnswer(true, new int[] { 1, 2 });
        else
            return StrDiff.ReturnAnswer(false, new int[] { 2, 3 });
    }
}
```

В данном случае все отлично работает, но если я хочу наследовать класс и заменить в нем `StupidPaper` на `TimeFrame` код `StrDiff` реализующий метод `SignalFilterAnswer` повторяется дважды.

```
//наследуем базовый класс, реализуя только метод OpenFilterAnswer
abstract class TimeFrameImplementation : BaseStrategy
{
    //open filter
    TimeFrame TimeFrame = new TimeFrame();

    //реализуем метод, который выполняет работу "open filter"
    protected override bool OpenFilterAnswer(decimal IncomeValue)
    {
        // этот IF для того чтобы показать, что используются protected переменные базового класса
        if(VariableForOpen > IncomeValue)
            return TimeFrame.ReturnAnswer(new byte[] { 144, 4 });
        else
            return TimeFrame.ReturnAnswer(new byte[] { 12, 4 });
    }
}

//наследуем TimeFrameImplementation и оставшуюся часть реализуем в этом классе
class TimeFrameStrDiffStrategy : TimeFrameImplementation
{
    //signal filter
    StrDiff StrDiff = new StrDiff();

    //реализуем метод, который выполняет работу "signal filter"
    protected override bool SignalFilterAnswer(decimal IncomeValue)
    {
        //////////////////////////////////////////
        // Проблема находиться тут, этот код уже был написан в классе StupidPaperStrDiffStrategy и повторяется в этом классе
        /////////////////////////////////////////
        if(VariableForSignal < IncomeValue)
            return StrDiff.ReturnAnswer(true, new int[] { 1, 2 });
        else
            return StrDiff.ReturnAnswer(false, new int[] { 2, 3 });
    }
}
```

Comment: Если ответ не решил вашу проблему, тогда зачем вы пометили его как принятый? Теперь этот вопрос могут закрыть как дубликат предыдущего вопроса.

Comment: я не сразу понял, что вопрос не решен, попробовал, все получилось, а потом когда начал реализовывать, выяснилась эта проблема

Comment: Реализовать `//опрашиваем второй фильтр` через интерфейсы у меня не получилось, потому что все сущности `StrDiff`, `TimeFrame`, `StupidPaper` преимущественно принимают разные входящие переменные

Comment: так вынеси этот код в функцию, возможно даже generic и вызывай с нужными параметрами. Примечательно, что код в принципе разный.